# Ansible - Unable to get variables to work

Tags: ansible

I am testing the `variable` feature in ansible along with `include_vars` and `with_first_found`.

My playbook is

```
---
- name: Load Variables from files.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "a.yml"
    - "b.yml"
    - "default.yml"

- name: another play
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="hello {{ http_port }}"
```

But when Im running this, I get the ERROR,

```
# ansible-playbook -i inventory/plat-inventory test.yaml 
ERROR! 'with_first_found' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/root/config-3.0.98/ansible/test.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Load Variables from files.
  ^ here
```

default.yml states :

```
http_port: 80
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `include_vars` should be a task, as the examples in [its documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html)

something like

```
- name: playbook
  hosts: somehosts
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: "add some vars"
      include_vars: somefile.yml
```

But then, those variables won't probably be available in the other playbook.